# Ordenar por fecha en Angular

Tags: html, angular, aplicación-web

Tengo tareas que voy agregando en un formulario y debo seleccionar una fecha de inicio y una fecha de termino, al momento de guardar la tarea, se muestra en una lista que tengo, pero se agregan de forma que la ultima que se agrego queda en primera posición y mi idea es hacer que se agreguen de la mas antigua hasta la mas nueva.

Aquí esta el html:

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-subtitle>
        Tareas
    </mat-card-subtitle>
</mat-card-header>
<mat-card-content>
    <mat-toolbar  *ngIf="dataSource.length===0" >
        <span>No hay Tareas que mostrar</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <table *ngIf="dataSource.length>0" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" > 
        <ng-container matColumnDef="taskName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nombre de la tarea</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.taskName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="taskState">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Estado </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
            <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" [(ngModel)]="element.taskState " (click)="changeState(element.id, element.taskState)">
                Estado
            </mat-slide-toggle></td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Fecha de inicio</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.startDate |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="asOfDate">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Fecha de Termino</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.asOfDate |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="updateAt">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Últ. Actualización</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.updatedAt |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="acciones">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="text-align: right;">
                <div class="example-button-container">
                    <button (click)="selectTask(element.id)" mat-mini-fab  aria-label="Example icon button with a menu icon">
                        <mat-icon>border_color</mat-icon></button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>   
    </table>
</mat-card-content>
```

No se como poder ordenar las fechas.

Código del TS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías compartir el código del componente.ts

Comment: aunque no muestras el codigo del servicio Es un array de objetos por lo cual podes seleccionar en que lugar insertar al nuevo objeto con `arr.splice(index, 0, {objetoTarea}); insertamos un objeto tarea dentro de un array de tarea  en un especifico index` tambien se puede agregar matSort a la tabla para ordenar por fecha. Si te puede ser de utilidad decime

Answer (score 1):

Para que una tarea se agregue en la ultima fila se puede usar arr.splice(index, 0, {objetoTarea}) aplicándolo al array de tareas un ejemplo de esto en un borrador mío también en el código de la respuesta forma de ordenar por fecha [github pages](https://nestdanchia.github.io/add/).

```js
//modulo.ts
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar'; 
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";

const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    FormsModule 
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
//component.ts
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDatepickerInputEvent } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
// https://nestdanchia.github.io/add/
import * as _moment from 'moment';
const moment = _moment;
class Articulo {
  constructor(public taskName: string, public taskState: string,
    public startDate: Date, public asOfDate: Date, public updatedAt: Date) {
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  startDatePick = new Date(2022, 3, 1);
  date = moment();

  selDate!: string;
  selDay !: string;
  selMonth !: string;
  selYear !: string;

  title = "hola";
  dataSource: any;
  articuloselect: Articulo = new Articulo("", "", new Date(), new Date(), new Date());
  @ViewChild(MatTable) tabla1!: MatTable<Articulo>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;
  columnas: string[] = ['taskName', 'taskState', 'startDate', 'asOfDate', 'updatedAt'];
  datos: Articulo[] = [new Articulo('Deportes', 'Activo', new Date(2022, 4, 1), new Date(2022, 4, 21), new Date(2022, 4, 5)),
  new Articulo('Cine', 'Activo', new Date(2022, 8, 1), new Date(2022, 8, 18), new Date(2022, 8, 5)),
  new Articulo('Ajedrez', 'Activo', new Date(2022, 10, 1), new Date(2022, 10, 29), new Date(2022, 10, 14)),
  ];
  ngOnInit() {

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Articulo>(this.datos);
    console.log('ngOnInit this.datos:', this.datos)
    console.log(this.dataSource);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  agregar() {
    let index=this.datos.length;
    console.log(index)
    let nuevaTarea = new Articulo(this.articuloselect.taskName,
      this.articuloselect.taskState, this.articuloselect.startDate,
      this.articuloselect.asOfDate, this.articuloselect.updatedAt)
    console.log(nuevaTarea);
    this.datos.splice(index, 0, nuevaTarea);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Articulo>(this.datos);
    this.tabla1.renderRows();
    this.articuloselect = new Articulo("", "", new Date("2015-03-25"), new Date(), new Date());
  }
  onDateChange($event: any) {
    console.log($event.value, moment($event.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    const formatted = moment($event.value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    console.log(formatted)

  }
  addEvent(type: string, event: MatDatepickerInputEvent<Date>) {
    this.date = moment(event.value);
    this.selDate = this.date.format('DD');
    this.selDay = this.date.format('dddd');
    this.selMonth = this.date.format('MMMM');
    this.selYear = this.date.format('YYYY');
  }

}
```

```html
//vista.html
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-subtitle>
      Tareas
    </mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <mat-toolbar>

    </mat-toolbar>
    <table #table1 mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="taskName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Nombre de la tarea</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.taskName }} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="taskState">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Estado </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.taskState}}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Fecha de inicio</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.startDate |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="asOfDate">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Fecha de Termino</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.asOfDate |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="updatedAt">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Últ. Actualización</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.updatedAt |date:'dd/MM/yy'}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnas"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnas;"></tr>
    </table>
  </mat-card-content>


  <div class="contenedor">
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="articuloselect.taskName" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese taskName">
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput [(ngModel)]="articuloselect.taskState" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese taskState">
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>startDate</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="mydateX" [(ngModel)]="articuloselect.startDate"
          (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)"
          placeholder="Pick a startDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="mydateX"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #mydateX>
        </mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>asOfDate</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="mydateA" [(ngModel)]="articuloselect.asOfDate"
          (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)"
          placeholder="Pick a asOfDate">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="mydateA"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #mydateA>
        </mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>updatedAt</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="mydateB" [(ngModel)]="articuloselect.updatedAt"
          (dateInput)="addEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)"
          placeholder="Pick a updatedAt">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="mydateB"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #mydateB>
        </mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </p>
    <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="agregar()">Agregar</button>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <h3>Selecionaste fecha</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Date: {{selDate}}</li>
    <li>Day: {{selDay}}</li>
    <li>Month: {{selMonth}}</li>
    <li>Year: {{selYear}}</li>
  </ul>


  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```